# Can't choose a different option in Promoted Builds choice on second promotion

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using the Promoted Builds plugin in Jenkins for deployment of my application into different environments.

I have a manual promotion defined, with a "choice" approval parameter, containing two entries - one corresponding to each of two instances of my application. This generates a drop-down list available at manual promotion time.

The promotion executes a Windows batch script which uses the value from the drop down list to choose what directories to write to, what config files to edit etc.

This works perfectly well - once.

If I want to promote the same build to BOTH environments, I would expect to just be able to execute the promotion twice, choosing each environment in turn from the generated drop down list.

However, when I go to do this, I find that the drop down list has now become a read-only text box that I can't choose the other environment from.

Clearly this is a deliberate design choice - so I would really appreciate some feedback on how best to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 2 promotions for build jobs. `Deploy to DEV` and `Deploy to QA`.

Yes, you got to do a little more maintenance, because as your number of environments grows, you got to have a promotion job for each. However there are also benefits: each promotion has a different colored star on the build's history, so it's easy to tell just by glancing which builds have been deployed to DEV and which have been deployed to QA.

**Update:**

If the content of the promotion steps is large, two ways to manage it are:

- Save a shell script to SVN and call it from the promotion step
- Use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Managed+Script+Plugin to manager a script centrally in Jenkins and then reference it from the promotion step

Comment: I was resistant to doing this because the promotion script is long, and I would not want to duplicate it. However, thinking about it, if I just check the script in to SVN, I can call it with a command line argument - which I can set in two different promotions easily. Cheers for the inspiration.

Comment: I personally use shell scripts in SVN for this as well. However another alternative is https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Managed+Script+Plugin . It allows you to manage a shell script centrally through Jenkins, and then reference it in build steps